# how can i use stop for the second time?

Tags: javascript

i click "stop" (in form-input) the clock stop but when i click "stop" after  clicking "begin", it can not run.My question is how can i run stop for the second time? thank you all.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>setInterval</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var i=setInterval("clock()",100);
        function clock()
        {
            var time=new Date();
            document.getElementById("clock").value = time;
        }

       function stop(){
           clearInterval(i);
       }
       function begin(){
            setInterval("clock()",100);
       }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="clock" size="50"  />
    <input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="stop()"  />
    <input type="button" value="Begin" onclick="begin()"  />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you're not saving the interval id inside `begin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in `setInterval` function we need to pass the function, not to call. `setInterval`  automatically invoke it after specified time like `setInterval(clock, 100);`

Second, You need to store the interval `ID` again to stop it(clear it). You need to refactor your `begin` function so that it can store the new interval `ID` that `setInterval` returns

```
i = setInterval(clock, 100);
```

```js
var i = setInterval(clock, 100);

function clock() {
  var time = new Date();
  document.getElementById("clock").value = time;
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(i);
}

function begin() {
  i = setInterval(clock, 100);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="clock" size="50" />
  <input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="stop()" />
  <input type="button" value="Begin" onclick="begin()" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear interval requires an id of the interval to clear. You are setting the `i` identifier in the first interval but after that you are not updating it for new interval. You need to update `i` to the new id so that the latest interval is cleared. Try this.

```
function begin(){
    i = setInterval("clock()",100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Must be synchronized to setInterval i inside the begin function.

`function begin(){ i = setInterval("clock()",100); }`